# Creating an XML sitemap with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap that will automatically update. I've done something similiar with my RSS feed, but this sitemap refuses to work. You can view it live at http://designdeluge.com/sitemap.xml I think the main problem is that its not recognizing the PHP code. Here's the full source:

```
 <?php 


include 'includes/connection.php';

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd">

    <url>
        <loc>http://designdeluge.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2010-04-20</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://designdeluge.com/about.php</loc>
        <lastmod>2010-04-20</lastmod>
        <changefreq>never</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>

    <?php

    $entries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Entries");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($entries)) {
    $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['timestamp']));

    echo "

    <url>
        <loc>http://designdeluge.com/".$title."</loc>
        <lastmod>".$date."</lastmod>
        <changefreq>never</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>";

 } ?>

</urlset>
```

The problem is that the dynamic URL's (e.g. the ones pulled from the DB) aren't being generated and the sitemap won't validate. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Right now, I'm just trying to get the code itself working. I have it set up as a PHP file on my local testing server. The code above is being used. Right now, nothing displays nothing on screen or in the source. I'm thinking I made a syntax error, but I can't find anything. Any and all help is appreciated!

**EDIT 2:** Ok, I got it sorted out guys. Apparently, I had to echo the xml declaration with PHP. The final code is posted above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: You should use UTF-8 encoded URL in your sitemap. I can't see any code you used to encode your dynamically generated URLs.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you take a look at the `sitemap.xml` that's generated *(using view source, in your browser, for example)*, you'll see this :

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84" xmlns:xsi="http:/
...
```

The `<?php`, present in that output, shows that **PHP code is not interpreted**.

This is probably because **your webserver doesn't recognize `.xml` as an extension of files that should contain PHP code**.

At least two possible solutions :

- Re-configure your server, so XML files go through the PHP interpreter *(might not be such a good idea : that can cause problems with existing files ! )*
- Change the extension of your sitemap, to `sitemap.php` for example, so it's interpreted by your server.

I would add another solution :

- Have a `sitemap.php` file, that contains the code
- And **use a RewriteRule** so the `sitemap.xml` URL actually points to the `sitemap.php` file

With that, you'll have the `sitemap.xml` URL, which is nice *(required ? )*, but as the code will be in `sitemap.php`, it'll get interpreted.

See **[Apache's `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**.

Comment: Well the only two .xml files on my server are using php so I don't see any harm. Would doing the first option be something like adding this to a .htaccess file? AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml

Comment: Not sure this can be done in a `.htaccess` file *(depending ohn your server's configuration, it might be necessary to do it directly in the configuration of the server)* ;; but you could try, maybe it'll work :-)

Comment: @iMaster: For your code to work, short_tags must also be off (it is by default--just something to be aware of).  Additionally, when I currently visit http://designdeluge.com/sitemap.xml I get an HTTP 500 response, so your config is broken (probably 'cause you're working on it right now).  Lastly, for large sites, generating the whole sitemap in realtime is probably infeasible -- so if you're expecting to grow to thousands of pages or more, be prepared to reimplement this later.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing that 500 Error...all I added to my .htaccess file are the two rewrite rules, but I don't think that's causing it. I added this: 

RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

Not sure why that's causing an error... Is there any way to get more info on what's causing an error like that?

Comment: here is a gud example of .htaccess file http://pingbin.com/2011/03/sitemap-php-to-sitemap-xml-htaccess-file/

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution is to add to your apache `.htaccess` file the following line after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

and then simply having a file `sitemap.php` in your root folder that would be normally accessible via `http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml`, the default URL where all search engines will firstly search.

The file `sitemap.php` shall start with

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8') ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

I've used William's code (thanks) and with a few small modifications it worked for me.

I think the line:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

should be the second line after the top `<?php`

Incidentally, just a small point to anyone else that copies it, but there is a single space character before the `<?php` in the first line - if you inadvertantly copy it as I did, you will spend a bit of time trying to figure out why the code won't work for you!

I had to tweak the MySql select statement a little bit too.

Finally, in the output, I have used a variable $domain so that this piece of code can be used as a template without the need to think about it (provided you use the same table name each time). The variabe is added to the connectdb.php file which is included to connect to the database.

Here is my working version of the William's code:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
include 'includes/connectdb.php';
?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd">

    <url>
        <loc>http://www.DOMAIN.co.uk/</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>

    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE onshow = 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);      
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
    $filename = stripslashes($row['filename']);
    ?>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.<?php echo "$domain"; ?>/<?php echo "$filename" ?></loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>

 <?php } ?>

</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to creating and updating `sitemap.xml` file.

```php
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

require_once('database.php');

$sitemapText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset
          xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
      <loc>http://ajkhub.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2021-08-18T18:32:09+00:00</lastmod>
      <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://ajkhub.com/includes/about.php</loc>
      <lastmod>2021-08-18T18:32:09+00:00</lastmod>
      <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://ajkhub.com/includes/privacy-policy.php</loc>
      <lastmod>2021-08-18T18:32:09+00:00</lastmod>
      <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://ajkhub.com/includes/termsandcondition.php</loc>
      <lastmod>2021-08-18T18:32:09+00:00</lastmod>
      <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM page ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$sitemapText .= ' <url>
                 <loc>'.$actual_link."/".$row['page'].'</loc>
                 <lastmod>'.date(DATE_ATOM,time()).'</lastmod>
                 <priority>0.80</priority>
               </url>';
   }
}

$sitemapText .= '</urlset>';

$sitemap = fopen("sitemap.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($sitemap, $sitemapText);
fclose($sitemap);
```