# dynamically create sitemap xml using php

Tags: php, entity, sitemap

I have created sitemap for my site using some reference code in the below link

[Creating an XML sitemap with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747801/creating-an-xml-sitemap-with-php)

But I am getting error as

XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location:

as my content is as follows

<< alt >> attribute and it says something like

< loc >http://www.example.com/700- & laquo;alt & raquo;-attributes-in-images.php< /loc >

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Dynamically isn't really a good tag name. It doesn't really add any value to the post.

Comment: Hi,

Still I haven't solved this..Anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Please provide the code you use to generate the fragment that raises the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to use the `urlencode()` function on the link value and reconvert the entities before using `html_entity_decode()`:

```
echo '<loc>'.urlencode(html_entity_decode($link)).'<loc>';
```

or something similar in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to have access to you root folder and add to your Apache `.htaccess` file the following lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule sitemap\.xml sitemap.php [L]
```

and then simply having a file `sitemap.php` in your root folder that therefore would be normally accessible via `http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml`, the default URL where all search engines will firstly search.

That file `sitemap.php` shall start with

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8') ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ?>
```

I have this solution and it works like a charm :)